# How to specify a file extension mask with MATLAB dir function

Tags: matlab, listbox

I'm working on GUI matlab I want display only sound waves in a listbox from a specific folder. When I click on a button the sound wav will be listed in a listbox. The code I'm using diplays all what is in the folder.

```
function Display_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to pushbutton4 (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)

d = dir('c:\savedsound'); %get files
set(handles.listbox1,'String',{d.name})
```

Comment: add `\*.wav` at the end of  the string in `dir`

Comment: Thanks, it worked. In my GUI I have a plot button, when I choose a sound from my listbox , the sound must be plotted. But I didn't find any code that plots the sound choosen from the listbox. Please any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to show only **.wav** files, you can simply modify your call to **dir**.

```
d = dir('C:\savedsound\*.wav'); % get files
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked. In my GUI I have a plot button, when I choose a sound from my listbox , the sound must be plotted.  But I didn't find any code that plots the sound choosen from the listbox. Please any help

Comment: Take a look at the wavread function. I bet you can find a good example here on StackOverflow.